# Wordpress Frontend plugin error with ajax calling in response from action function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In the main plugin file, i wrote this code.

```
wp_enqueue_script('tihom_ajax', plugins_url( '/js/tihom_ajax.js' , __FILE__ ) , array( 'jquery' ));
wp_localize_script( 'tihom_ajax', 'TihomAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php') ));

function tihom_rating_action() 
{
  echo "ID is : ".$_POST['id'];
  $wpdb->insert('wp_rating', array( 'rating' => (int) $_POST['rating'], 'page_id' => $_POST['id']));
  echo "Done";
  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_the_ajax_hook', 'tihom_rating_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_the_ajax_hook', 'tihom_rating_action');
```

And in script file code is:

```
function updateRadioButton(rating){
  jQuery.post(TihomAjax.ajaxurl, jQuery("#theForm").serialize(), function(response_from_the_action_function) {       
    jQuery("#schemarating").html(response_from_the_action_function); 
  });
}
```

There is no error in my code when i check it through search console. But "schemarating" div is updated to "0". means no response_from_the_action_function is received. I am not able to locate the error. Help me out please.

Comment: Please take care to format your code so it's readable.

Comment: are you defining action=the_ajax_hook anywhere in your form? This needs to be passed as a post parameter, so that WP knows which ajax action to perform

Comment: yes I have defined <input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook" /> in my form @OleHaugset

Comment: go and check what's received in `admin-ajax.php` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually assign `action` to `ajax request`: so lets say...

```
add_action('wp_ajax_SOME', function(){die('42')});
```

Means that, when you sending query var action with value 'SOME', admin-ajax.php will try to call this callback.

quick memo: `nopriv` call for frontend (non logged in users), another one for backend (for logged-in users).

Personally, I have run into this issue many times, all of them was my fault. I forgot to initiate a request or pass action var. So, sometimes you need to open admin-ajax.php and check what vars received in order to solve problem.

Comment: Ole, it doesn't matter what `he did`. It doesn't work: and there only two possible reasons for that: 1) there is no such action assigned to this post/get/request action at the moment when action triggered; 2) there is no post/get/request action passed to `do_action` callback. So OP needs to debug this sutuation himself a bit.

Comment: Still, this is not an answer to his question, as you are telling him to do what he have already shown us that he has done, and as for passing the action var, he have replied to this in the comments to his question.